# English equivalent for the French "procès d'intention"

Tags: expressions, translation

The "[Procès d'intention](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc%C3%A8s_d%27intention)" is a fallacy of trying to discredit someone by accusing them of bad and deceiving intentions.

Is there an English equivalent for this? In Romanian it's used quite a lot in the media, I would be surprised if the English language doesn't have something similar.

Comment: "ulterior motive" might be a possible phrase.

Comment: ***Motive questioning***: http://prospect.org/article/problem-motive-questioning

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be equivalent to the [*furtive fallacy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furtive_fallacy), which appears in [Wikipedia’s List of Fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies) as an *informal fallacy*.

Comment: Wikipedia lists it under the ad hominem category and even has an entire article on it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_motive